# JFreechart - How to add extra info in tooltip

Tags: tooltip, jfreechart

### The Problem

I'm trying to show additional info in tooltip.

### Tools Used

I'm using the *StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator*.

### What I have tried so far

The original values retrieved from database are elaborated before they are associated to the CategorydataSet.

### The Goal to Achieve

I would like to show the original value in the tooltip.. Is it possible? I only can load the {0}, {1}, {2} values, maybe there's a way to store additional info in categorydata set?

Thank you for support,
Michela

Comment: Could you post some of the code?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=117044).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `StandardCategoryItemLabelGenerator` and override `generateToolTip`. With access to the `dataset`, you can put pretty much anything in the tooltip. For example,

```
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();
BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setBaseToolTipGenerator(new StandardCategoryToolTipGenerator(){

    @Override
    protected String generateLabelString(CategoryDataset dataset, int row, int col) {
        return dataset.getColumnKey(col) + " " + dataset.getValue(row, col);
    }
});
```